# how do you print values ones

Tags: python

I am retrieving data from vcenter and printing the values for each exs hosts. The problem is that for some reason, I am printing some values twice.  I need to make sure that I print the the same values only once:

Here is a sample results set:

```
    name => web01 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-648 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 3149 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 87051

name => web02 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-658 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 4909 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 144503

name => web03 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-664 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 2659 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 123063

name => web04 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-670 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 1445 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 111676

name => web05 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-856 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 983 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 116179

name => web05 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-856 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 983 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 116179

name => web06 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-858 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 1073 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 141572

name => web06 summary.hardware.cpuMhz => 2194 summary.hardware.memorySize => 274707304448 summary.hardware.numCpuCores => 16 summary.host => host-858 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 1073 summary.quickStats.overallMemoryUsage => 141572
```

I've update the code as this:

```
for item in results:
        props = dict((p.Name, p.Val) for p in item.PropSet)
        name = props['name']
        tt=int(time.time())

        Ballooned_Memory = props.get('summary.quickStats.balloonedMemory')
        if Ballooned_Memory is not None:
                Metric="vSphereGuest.ballooned_memory"
                print Metric,tt,Ballooned_Memory,"vSphereGuest="+name.replace('"', ''),"source=vSphereGuest","dc=dc1"

        Cpu_Demand = props.get('summary.quickStats.overallCpuDemand')
        if Cpu_Demand is not None:
                Metric="vSphereGuest.Cpu_Demand"
                print Metric,tt,Cpu_Demand,"vSphereGuest="+name.replace('"', ''),"source=vSphereGuest","dc=dc1"
```

It goes throught each result set and prints out values. There seems to be one issue left. If the result set includes duplicates (it comes from source like that), I will print out the same data set twice. How could I modify this so that I only print out one regardless of how many the same result set comes from the source?

Comment: please fix indentation

Comment: Your key is `r.name`+`p.Name`?

Comment: @Micheled'Amico, I've update the original post.

Comment: When you present the "sample results set," what do you mean? Is that text you're trying to parse? It certainly is not a Python data structure. Nor does it contain the `summary.capacity` or `summary.freeSpace` keys your code appears to be searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the many comments and updates, the problem is getting a little clearer. Updated yet again, for still more new data:

```
class Seen(set):
    def seen(self, x):
        answer = x in self
        self.add(x)
        return answer

previously = Seen()
for item in results:
    props = dict((p.Name, p.Val) for p in item.PropSet)
    name = props['name']
    if previously.seen(name):
        continue
    Total_Space = props.get('summary.capacity')
    if Total_Space is not None:
        Metric="vSphereDatastore.space_total"
        print Metric,int(time.time()),Total_Space,"datastore="+name,"source="+"vSphereDatastore","dc="+"dc1"
    Free_Space = props.get('summary.freeSpace')
    if Free_Space is not None:
        Metric="vSphereDatastore.space_free"
        print Metric,int(time.time()),Free_Space,"datastore="+name,"source="+"vSphereDatastore","dc="+"dc1"
```

The problem with the original code is that you are double-iterating, and not to good effect. This cleans up the process a little by creating a temporary dictionary with all of the key-value combinations found in `item.PropSet`. If `item.PropSet` supports indexing (`item.PropSet['name']`) or getting (`item.PropSet.get('name')`), then creating `props` is redundant, and you can substitute `item.PropSet` for `props`. If not, keep `props`. Either way, you now have direct access to each key-value pair in the property set.

Props will look something like this (for `'web-03'`):

```
{'config.hardware.memoryMB': '4096',
 'config.hardware.numCPU': '2',
 'name': 'web-03',
 'summary.quickStats.balloonedMemory': '0',
 'summary.quickStats.hostMemoryUsage': '4140',
 'summary.quickStats.overallCpuDemand': '1777',
 'summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage': '1031',
 'summary.quickStats.staticCpuEntitlement': '1099',
 'summary.quickStats.swappedMemory': '0',
 'summary.runtime.host': 'host-648'}
```

You still have a serious problem, in that *neither* of the property keys you're looking for (`'summary.capacity'` and `'summary.freeSpace'`) appear in `item.PropSet`, based on the results you reported for `for p in item.PropSet: print p.Name, "=>", p.Val, print "\n"`.

But once you figure that out, there are other improvements you can make, e.g. by abstracting out some of your repeated code. E.g.:

```
def print_metric(metric, value, datastore, source="vSphereDatastore", dc='dc1'):
    print metric, int(time.time()), value,"datastore="+datastore,"source="+source,"dc="+dc

previously = Seen()
for item in results:
    props = dict((p.Name, p.Val) for p in item.PropSet)
    name = props['name']
    if previously.seen(name):
        continue
    Total_Space = props.get('summary.capacity')
    if Total_Space is not None:
        print_metric("vSphereDatastore.space_total", Total_Space, name)
    Free_Space = props.get('summary.freeSpace')
    if Free_Space is not None:
        print_metric("vSphereDatastore.space_free", Free_Space, name)
```

Or even more spare:

```
def print_metric(metric, value, datastore, source="vSphereDatastore", dc='dc1'):
    if value is None:
        return
    print metric, int(time.time()), value,"datastore="+datastore,"source="+source,"dc="+dc

previously = Seen()
for item in results:
    props = dict((p.Name, p.Val) for p in item.PropSet)
    name = props['name']
    if previously.seen(name):
        continue
    print_metric("vSphereDatastore.space_total", props.get('summary.capacity'), name)
    print_metric("vSphereDatastore.space_free", props.get('summary.freeSpace'), name)
```

Comment: this line giving invalid syntax:   props = { p.Name: p.Val for p in item.PropSet }
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Jonathon Eunice, I am getting invalid syntax on this line "props = { p.Name: p.Val for p in item.PropSet }"

Comment: That's a dictionary comprehension. What version of Python are you using? 2.6 or earlier? Try `dict((p.Name, p.Val) for p in item.PropSet)` as a backwards-compatible alternative.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6.9

Comment: For security, compatibility, and other reasons, you should upgrade to 2.7 at your earliest convenience.

Comment: @Jonathon Eunice, my early observation telling me that this is great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jonathon Eunice, I am still seeing some duplicates but not as much. I think it is due to the data source. is there anything else I can do on top this code to only take the first occorrence of data?

Comment: @user1471980 I can't determine that without a true data set. You're showing us only part of the data, I take it? We'd need to see a larger, truer version of the data to understand where the duplication is occurring.

Comment: I've update the original post with some data. Look at the last 4 lines that start with name =>. It looks like some times I am getting duplicate records when I poll the vcenter and this is causing problems inserting this data set to opentsdb. When I run this script, I only need to print out one unique line per script line.

Comment: Ok, final contribution. Note the class `Seen` and its use as a cache of previously seen items.

Comment: your help with this was beyond my imagination. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `set()` to take care of what you had already printed:

```
cache = set()
for item in results:
    for r in item.PropSet:
        if r.Name == "name":
            for p in item.PropSet:
                try:
                    v = p.Val
                except AttributeError:
                    #We don't care the property without val attribute
                    continue
                if not v in cache:
                    cache.add(v)
                    if p.Name=="summary.capacity":
                        Total_Space=v
                        Metric="vSphereDatastore.space_total"
                        print Metric,int(time.time()),v,"datastore="+name,"source="+"vSphereDatastore","dc="+"dc1"

                    if p.Name=="summary.freeSpace":
                        Free_Space=v
                        Metric="vSphereDatastore.space_free"
                        print Metric,int(time.time()),v,"datastore="+name,"source="+"vSphereDatastore","dc="+"dc1"
```

Comment: Where is `p` assigned? In line 5, won't it complain about use before assignment?

Comment: @JonathanEunice but maybe your is the real fix.... I'll remove my answer because it is just a WA of the real issue!

Comment: @JonathanEunice I must wait tomorrow... I've already used my 5 deletions for a day :)

Comment: @Micheled'Amico, JonathanEunice answer wont work for this particular situation. I'll try yours.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico, I get this error:  if not p.val in cache():
AttributeError: 'DynamicProperty_Holder' object has no attribute 'val'

Comment: @Micheled'Amico, I've update the post with the results set, hopefully that will help.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico, it is not printing anything.

Comment: @user1471980 sorry I didn't see that is a capital v in val

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65980/discussion-between-michele-damico-and-user1471980).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be iterating over `item.PropSet` in a nested fashion, first with `r` then with `p`. Try instead:

```
for item in results:
    for p in item.PropSet:
        if p.Name=="summary.capacity":
            Total_Space=p.Val
            Metric="vSphereDatastore.space_total"
            print Metric,int(time.time()),p.Val,"datastore="+name,"source="+"vSphereDatastore","dc="+"dc1"
        elif p.Name=="summary.freeSpace":
            Free_Space=p.Val
            Metric="vSphereDatastore.space_free"
            print Metric,int(time.time()),p.Val,"datastore="+name,"source="+"vSphereDatastore","dc="+"dc1"
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. I need to do this for each servers in results set

Comment: name is also in propset, I have to retrieve name and print results for each name. name is the server name. That's where it gets little tricky.

Comment: @user1471980 I don't understand your objection. You are iterating over `item.PropSet` twice. It doesn't change during your iteration. The outer loop is dysfunctional. It's like a clock that's stopped. It's still right twice each day.

Comment: please take a look at my post, I've updated with results set. What would name be equal to under your answer? when I run your code, I get: NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: @user1471980 Yes, but you should get that error when you run your code, too, because `name` is not defined within the code presented there. I assumed it was something external. Where do you expect `name` to be set? Or to what do you expect it to be set?

Comment: when I run this: for p in item.PropSet:
        print p.Name, "=>", p.Val,
    print "\n"
I get, something like this: config.hardware.memoryMB => 4096 config.hardware.numCPU => 2 name => web-01 summary.quickStats.balloonedMemory => 0 summary.quickStats.hostMemoryUsage => 4138 summary.quickStats.overallCpuDemand => 2062 summary.quickStats.overallCpuUsage => 1162 summary.quickStats.staticCpuEntitlement => 776 summary.quickStats.swappedMemory => 0 summary.runtime.host => host-914 so for each line, I have to grab name other metrics belong to that name.

Comment: @user1471980 Okay, then that is text from your print statements. Is `PropSet` indexable or `get`-able? I.e., does `item.PropSet['name']` or `item.PropSet.get('name')` work?

Comment: for both, I get this error:  for p in item.PropSet:
NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: @user1471980 That's not really possible. If `item` isn't defined, then none of the code that dereferences `item.PropSet` will ever run. It's true that `item` is only defined *during the context of* the `for item in results:` loop. But if `item` is not defined, there are no results.